# Junit Testing with an Array List

Tags: java, junit, arraylist

I have a method set up to add users to an `ArrayList`, and return `false` if the same user is added:

```
public boolean addUser(K pass, V user)
{
    if (username.contains(user))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        password.add(pass);
        username.add(user);
        size++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then I have a JUnit test to `assertFalse(true)` because that's what my method returns when adding two users with the same name:

```
@Test
public void testAddingTwoOfTheSameUserToArrayList() {
    User<String, String> user1 = new User<String, String>();
    user1.addUser("password", "SpeedinDave");
    user1.addUser("password", "SpeedinDave");
    assertFalse(true);
}
```

However, it the test always turns up false (red bar). Any ideas?

Comment: what's username object?

Comment: What do you expect `assertFalse(true)` to do? And why are you never using the results of `addUser`?

Comment: you are wanting to assert the return value, so you need to capture the return value and pass that as the argument to `assertFalse()`

Comment: Your current "test" isn't actually testing your method.

Comment: First, what @Quetzalcoatl said. Second, if you do use `assertFalse` you should put in `false` NOT `true`.

Answer (score 8):

You should test something like that:

```
@Test
    public void testAddingTwoOfTheSameUserToArrayList() {
        User<String, String> user1 = new User<String, String>();
        user1.addUser("password", "SpeedinDave");
        assertFalse(user1.addUser("password", "SpeedinDave"););
    }
```

to be sure that the second `addUser()` returns false.

`assertFalse(b)` will succeed if the parameter b is false. So if you pass `true`, it will always fail.

Comment: It might also be worthwhile to modify the first `user1.addUser("password", "SpeedinDave");` to be `assertTrue(user1.addUser("password", "SpeedinDave"));`

Answer (score 3):

Right now you are not testing the return value of your `addUser()` method, but rather that the boolean constant `true` evaluates to `false` (this will never be true).  You probably want something like:

```
@Test
    public void testAddingTwoOfTheSameUserToArrayList() {
        User<String, String> user1 = new User<String, String>();
        assertTrue(user1.addUser("password", "SpeedinDave"));
        assertFalse(user1.addUser("password", "SpeedinDave"));
    }
```